# Getting the start time of a new process which I triggered

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Multiprocessing module in python and triggering many processes. Is there a way where I can find out the START TIME of each process that I triggered?

Since the processes are triggered quickly, I am looking to get the time in milliseconds or even in nanoseconds to differentiate each process.
This is the piece of code that I have,

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def myProcess(processName):
    print "This is a method that will run in parallel: processName"
    time.sleep(120)

num = 100

for n in range(1,num):
    processName = "Process %s" % n
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=myProcess,args=(processName))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

print "process startTime: %s " ?????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own wrapper class to record startime -

```
class Proc(object):
    def __init__(self,cmd)
        self.cmd = cmd

    def run(self):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=myProcess,args=(args))
        self.startime = datetime.datetime.now()
        proc.start()
        proc.join()  // Don't use this if you don't want to wait.


procobj = Proc(cmd)
procobj.run()
procobj.startime // gives you starttime
```

Comment: `procobj.run()` will cause your main program to hang until the subprocess has completed (due to the `join()` call).

Comment: Indeed it will. Kinda ruins the point of parallelizing, doesn't it? :p

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. `multiprocessing.Process` objects have a `pid` attribute -- the process ID, which is the process's unique identifier *at the OS level*. Use that instead.

Comment: yes, I tried, `proc.pid'. But I am not sure how to get the start time from this.

Comment: The entire point of my answer is that you *shouldn't* use the start time to identify each process (since the PID *is* the canonical unique identifier for a process). (If you want to know in which order the processes were started, just add them to a list as you start them.)

Comment: PIDs are *not* unique at the OS level. There *can* be different processes with the same PID... just not at the same time. The OS is free to reuse old PIDs for new processes. If you want a real unique identifier use the pair `(start_time, PID)`. Relying only on the PID when the process is ended is *unreliable*.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Queue` to the process and save the start times there:

```
def myProcess(processName,times):
    print "This is a method that will run in parallel: processName"
    times.put((processName,time.time()))
    time.sleep(120)

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
for n in range(num):
    processName = "Process %s" % n
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=myProcess,args=(processName,q))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

while not q.empty():
    a = q.get()
    print a
    "%s startTime: %f" % a
```